# Can I color different parts of text in a WPF TextBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, xml, textcolor

I've got a WPF TextBox into which my users type XHTML.

XAML...

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxContentBody"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         FontFamily="Consolas"
         ... />
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I'd rather that it looked like this (Photoshopped mock-up):

[image]

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Any chance of uploading the images to the stackoverflow hosting?

Answer (score 24):

You'll want to use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 12):

Like Kent said with a TextBox you're stuck with one color.

Here is a small article on simple RTB syntax highlighting that should give you most of what you need.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2006/12/14/RichTextBox-syntax-highlighting.aspx

Comment: I found the same article, but written in left to right format. Some readers may find this helpful: http://dedjo.blogspot.ca/2006/12/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom control inheriting the TextBox control and follow this example:

[Drawing Formatted Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drawing-formatted-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)