# WPF multi colored text for textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been unable to find a way to have multiple words colored differently using the textbox in WPF.  **I would like to use a textblock or Richtextbox but I have not been able to find any documentation that would allow me to get the index of the character that the mouse is over.**  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I color different parts of text in a WPF TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583597/can-i-color-different-parts-of-text-in-a-wpf-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetCharIndexFromPosition(Location)` method of the textbox :

```
private void Form_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int charindex = 0;
  TextBox tb;
  if (!(sender is TextBox))
     return;
  tb = (TextBox)sender;
  if(tb.TextLength == 0)
    return;

  charindex = tb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
}
```

For coloring multiple words differently, you can get some reference [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tamir/2006/12/14/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting/)

Hope this helps!!